# The use of "this" in every MATLAB class

Tags: matlab

Why is that in every class in MATLAB I must use "this"? I think that in C++ I don't need to use "this", only if I want to. Is this also the case in MATLAB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In short, you must use some kind of explicit reference.**

First of all, unlike in C++/C#/Java where it is named *this*, you can use any name you want.
The reason that you must use explicit calls is [Matlab designers decision](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/2008/sept/matlab-objects.html). 
The idea was to support Matlab vector operations on objects, as if they are 
structs. The following is a fragment from the link above:

> While languages with an implicit object parameter provide a "this" keyword 
>   to access the implicit object, they usually do not require you to access a 
>   property through "this". If MATLAB had implicit properties, the logical 
>   extension to array-based objects would be to index into nothing:
>   **S = S + (k).Value;**

**Edit:**
Following the good comment of @AndrewJanke, I would like to add that MATLAB could have had *this* as implicit reference, and only force to use it in indexing of array-based objects. Nevertheless, this approach was not chosen by MATLAB designers.

Comment: Python class methods are not required to name the explicit instance reference `self`.  It's also a convention, as in MATLAB.

Comment: I think this reading overlooks the core reason: multiple dispatch, obliquely referred to with "symmetry among multiple object parameters" in the linked article. E.g. for a method `f(A, B, C)`, any of the inputs might be the method dispatch object, or they could conceptually be peers, so it's not clear a priori which should become `this`. It could even be called as `f(2, 3, X)`. The indexing concern could be solved by having an implicit `this` parameter and just requiring you to use it when you were using `()`-indexing inside the method, like in C++ if you call an overloaded `[]`. (I think.)

Comment: @AndrewJanke, so basically you are saying that the main problem is the syntax *foo(obj)* instead of *obj.foo()*? An interesting thought. By the way, I agree that it could have been solved by having implicit parameter and using it only when indexing.

Comment: Yes, that  `foo(obj)` syntax and the functionality it supports. For example, it lets you use `plus()` to define `+` behavior in a commutative manner, or define classes that can be used as drop-in replacements for arguments to existing functions.